# How can I make these channels bigger to fit my wire?

Tags: selection-tools, 3d-printing

I am recreating Malt Whiskey's LED cube and using slightly bigger wire than he used (.8mm vs the .65mm he used). He has [a 3d printed jig to solder the LEDs](https://github.com/MaltWhiskey/Mega-Cube/blob/master/Construction/Jig%20Bottom%20A.stl) and there are "channels" for the wire to sit in. How do I make these channels bigger to accomodate my wire? I've tried selecting each channel individually but I'm not able to specify the depth and width. I'd imagine it would be faster to select all channels at the same time and adjust the size rather than individually. Thanks!

Comment: Which bits are the channels? The round holes? It would help us a lot if you made a couple of screen-grabs of the whole set-up, and the features you want to alter, and paste them into your question. Then we wouldn't have to go somewhere else, and guess.

Comment: The round holes are the LEDs. There are 8 channels that run the entire length of the jig and those are what I want to make bigger. Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to illustrate with a screen-grab, pointing out the channels, and share your .blend on https://blend-exchange.com/ so we can be sure solutions will work with your topology.